# Keycloak limit the number of sessions per realm

Tags: keycloak

I'm using keycloak as an Identity and Access Managements solution to secure both my frontend angular app and my backend spring boot app so my question is:
Is it possible to limit the number of sessions per realm while setting a Keycloak realm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Keycloak does not have the feature to limit the number of sessions per realm. You can see the enhance request:

[KEYCLOAK-849 - Enhance configurable session limits](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-849)

According to the Stian's (Keycloak Project Lead) comment at 07/Feb/19 8:53 AM on this page, you may be able to achieve with a **custom authenticator**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been implemented in the latest versions of Keycloak (since version 18) : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_user_session_limits